# Trying to parse a json string in vb6. Function already exists for parsing but the input vb6 expecting is different

Tags: json, vb6

I'm calling a web service in VB6 which returns a json string as response shown below. In the VB6 there is already a function written to parse all the requested data. This function is expecting an input in the format

```
 DIMfRec.output : "EPPC-00000EDIF0100004273333310001000000000XXXXXXXXX*XXXXXX        01032011360000877250000000000000000000000000000087725000057860FNJNJ7BL6AM000NA000020007036500002986
```

So now I would like to convert my JSON String output to the format the existing function is expecting. Any help with what that format is that the function is expecting and how to convert it so that it can be parsed using that function.

```
{
  "status" : "SUCCESS",
  "code" : "00",
  "businessErrorReason" : null,
  "technicalErrorReason" : null,
  "symphonyPolicyDetail" : {
    "requestType" : "IDRC",
    "symphonyPolicyDetails" : {
      "verb" : null,
      "hyphen" : null,
      "window" : null,
      "time" : 0,
      "app_type" : null,
      "illus_type" : null,
      "page_no" : null,
      "tot_no_bytes" : 0,
      "policy_number" : 0,
      "vers_number" : 0,
      "return_code" : null,
      "pending_sw" : null,
      "recovery_page" : null,
      "compression" : null,
      "trailer_len" : null,
      "insured_name" : "XXXXXXXXX*XXXXXX        ",
      "issue_mo" : 1,
      "issue_day" : 3,
      "issue_yr" : 2011,
      "attained_age" : 36,
      "net_premium1" : 87725,
      "net_premium2" : 0,
      "net_premium3" : 0,
      "net_premium4" : 0,
      "modal_perm" : 87725,
      "base_premium" : 57860,
      "sex" : "F",
      "state" : "NJ",
      "state_wr" : "NJ",
      "plan_series" : "7B",
      "plan_type" : "L",
      "occ_class" : "6AM",
      "rating" : 0,
      "class1" : "N",
      "prem_mode" : "A",
      "tax_benefit" : 0,
      "base_benefit" : 2000,
      "base_ben_per" : 70,
      "base_elim_per" : 365,
      "sss_premium" : 29865,
      "sss_benefit" : 1500,
      "sss_elim_per" : 365,
      "aib_amt_1" : 0,
      "aib_ben_per_1" : 0,
      "aib_amt_2" : 0,
      "aib_ben_per_2" : 0,
      "aib_sss_amt" : 0,
      "aib_sss_ben_per" : 0,
      "tax_disc" : 0,
      "er_exp_disc" : 0,
      "er_gsi_disc" : 0,
      "er_gti_disc" : 0,
      "er_disc" : 0,
      "er_plus_disc" : 0,
      "assoc_disc" : 0,
      "select_occ_disc" : 0,
      "mental_nerv_disc" : 0,
      "afl_disc" : 0,
      "total_discount_amt" : 0,
      "cola_type" : 0,
      "cola_prem" : 0,
      "reg_occ_type" : 0,
      "reg_occ_prem" : 0,
      "ben_updt" : 0,
      "abi" : 0,
      "rtw_prem" : 0,
      "res_dis_prem" : 0,
      "part_disb_prem" : 0,
      "lifetime_prem" : 0,
      "pro_prem" : 0,
      "pro_term_return" : "0000",
      "pro_perm_ret" : 0,
      "dividend" : 0,
      "net_prem_beg_yr_2" : 0,
      "net_prem_end_yr_2" : 0,
      "net_prem_beg_yr_3" : 0,
      "net_prem_end_yr_3" : 0,
      "net_prem_beg_yr_4" : 0,
      "net_prem_end_yr_4" : 0,
      "total_disc_pct" : 0,
      "eff_date_mo" : 1,
      "eff_date_slash" : "/",
      "eff_date_yr" : 2018,
      "next_ann_mo" : 1,
      "next_ann_slash" : "/",
      "next_ann_yr" : 2018,
      "occ_code" : 320,
      "rte" : 0,
      "etdb_prem" : 0,
      "etdb_factor" : 0,
      "rbr_prem" : 0,
      "rbr_ben_per" : 0,
      "stdb_prem" : 0,
      "stdb_ben_per" : 0,
      "cdb_benefit" : 0,
      "cdb_ben_per" : 0,
      "cdb_elim_per" : 0,
      "cdb_prem" : 0,
      "aio" : 0,
      "your_occ_ben_per" : 70,
      "tocc_ben_per" : 0,
      "claim_code" : 0,
      "mode_factor_code" : 3,
      "pdto_mo" : 1,
      "pdto_slash" : "/",
      "pdto_yr" : 2012,
      "cap" : 1,
      "pdb" : 1,
      "crp" : 0,
      "fbi" : 0,
      "issue_age" : 30,
      "shb" : 0,
      "multi_life" : 0,
      "resr" : 0,
      "filler" : "         ",
      "error_message_info" : "                                                                                "
    },
    "symphonyPolicy" : null
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to know the format of your existing record, then you can map your new JSON response to that record format.  I don't think anyone here is going to be able to assist with that - this is probably a format internal to your app, not much chance anyone knows what that is.

Comment: Are you sure you want to post a record which looks like it has a real person's name in it?